# Jira Assets API (Service Management) - Workspace Ids

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api, workspace

I'm using the JiraAssets API and on the documentation we need to specify a Jira WorkspaceId in the URL.

To retrieve the id we need to query this endpoint: /rest/servicedeskapi/insight/workspace

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/assets/assets-rest-api-guide/workflow/#step-2--discover-your-workspaceid

But, as mentioned here https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/service-desk/rest/api-group-assets/ this endpoint returns a list of workspaceIds.

The question is: Can a user really have access to more than 1 workspaceId. If yes how can I reproduce this scenario? Where can this WorkspaceId be found on the UI?